# Single slow website

Tags: performance, browser

I signed into a forum, I used it for awhile then all of a sudden it got super slow, I have to wait a long time for it to load. Most of the buttons don't work. I have good internet, only that website won't work. I tried getting into it with a family members account, and it worked using the same device. It's not my space either. I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: On your computer, try a different user account if your device allows you to make a new user account.

Comment: Like vonbrand said, it's very hard to answer that without more details. Generally though, if it's just this site that is slow, it's most likely the site's "fault", not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Without other details, it is almost impossible to answer.

- The site might have become suddenly very popular (your students, possibly many more interested), and just can't keep up with the load.
- The site could have some form of "free for a short period, if you don't pay it will be unbearably slow afterwards" (you state it requires some form of login, or it could track origin IPs)
- The site might be subject to a DoS attack
- It could be hosted at some facility that houses *other* very popular sites, or are subject to attack, and the site's resources just can't keep up.